# How to get only the first instance of an array that is true of a condition

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to modify my Wordpress-based Learning Management theme (called Academy on ThemeForest) to be able to work out which lesson in the current course the user is up to.

In other words, I want to run a check to see which lessons the user has completed, getting only the ID of the first lesson in the course hierarchy that has not been completed.

Here's everything I know:

Within the loop of a single post (in this case a "course"), this is how I get the array of the current course's lessons:

```
<?php $lessons_array = ThemexCourse::sortLessons(ThemexCourse::$data['course']['lessons']); ?>
```

This produces this nested array:

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ([ID] => 117 [menu_order]=>1) [1] => WP_Post Object ([ID] => 124 [menu_order]=>2) [2] => WP_Post Object ([ID] => 156 [menu_order]=>3))
```

I've truncated it a bit since the two values, [ID] and [menu_order], are the most important: they tell you the ID of each lesson and their hierarchy in the course.

But this is where I get stuck: I don't want to get all of the lesson IDs, just the one the user has yet to complete.

In order to check if a user has completed a lesson or not, I've been using this:

```
<?php if(ThemexCourse::isCompletedLesson($lesson_ID)) { echo 'Completed'; } ?>
```

So using the above information, is it possible to return a single ID of only the next incomplete lesson?

Thanks to anyone in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should do it:

```
$next_lesson = NULL;
foreach($lessons_array as $index=>$lesson) {
   if(!ThemexCourse::isCompletedLesson($lesson->ID)) {
       $next_lesson = $lesson;
       break;
   }
}

echo "Next lesson is: " . $next_lesson->ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but this returns the following error  "Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array" on line 3 of your code.